# Reading a text file in Perl, Searching for a Word, Returning Line Number

Tags: string, perl, search, file-io

I'm trying to write a piece of code that is called by some C code with the data file and a specific word being passed in as an argument, and the line number being outputted to stdout.  I played around with $substr some but that didn't work out.

I think it will ultimately be something like:

```
if ($oneLineofTheData !~ theSearchWord){
    counter++;
}
else{
    output counter to stdout
}
```

Would this be the easier way to handle this? How would I pass in the filename and search word? I'm very new to Perl so thank you in advance for helping out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in a file called whatever.pl:

```
$ct=0;
while(<>) {
  if ($_ =~ m/$ARGV[0]/) {
    print $ct;
    exit;
  }
  $ct++; 
}
```

Then on the command line run :

```
perl whatever.pl filename.txt wordToMatch
```

Comment: You can shorten the script by using `$.` instead of `$ct`. Also `$_ =~ m/$ARGV[0]/` can be abbreviated with `m/$ARGV[0]/`.

Comment: Ah, good calls @RenéNyffenegger.

Answer (score 3):

To pass arguments to a Perl program, use the `@ARGV` array.

To check for a presence of a substring in a string, use `index`.

`$.` keeps the line number of the last accessed filehandle.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($filename, $word) = @ARGV;

open my $FH, '<', $filename or die $!;
while (my $line = <$FH>) {
    if (-1 != index $line, $word) {
        print $.;
        exit
    }
}
```